# Where to install virtualenv packages

Tags: python, virtualenv

Which directory is it suggested to install Python packages in a `virtualenv`? For example:

```
$ sudo pip install requests
```

In which of the following directories should it be installed?  Or would it be installed somewhere else?

```
venv/
  - bin/
  - include/
  - lib/
```

What is the difference between those three folders?

Comment: Any reason you don't just want to let `pip` decide?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few misconceptions here:

- By using `sudo pip install` you're not using a virtualenv; you're installing those directly to your machine.
- You have to create the virtualenv and then activate it via `source venv/bin/activate`.
- Once it's activated, be sure that `pip` is installed. *Then*, you will be installing your packages directly to that virtualenv.  *Where* it's ultimately going to wind up in that virtualenv is best  left for pip to decide.